# I can/could imagine

Tags: modal-verbs

1. "As we walked through Facebook and Twitter, I **could imagine** myself sitting there coding throughout the day," she said. "I'm not afraid to be one of the first girls to go into one of those fields. I want to pursue this career and maybe a CEO of a company".
2. So it looks like I've got a ten-year lag between living in a place and writing about it. In ten years, I might try to write something about China. Really in all my life I've never seen anything like it. I **could imagine** myself writing about some New Jersey Dominican guy, doing the English-teaching expat thing in Shanghai. Maybe. I'm sure it would be really, really bad, too.(https://www.newyorker.com/books/page-turner/this-week-in-fiction-questions-for-junot-daz)
3. A hundred and fifty years ago, I **could imagine** myself gazing at a rainbow and wanting to understand it. But in a world where I have no idea how my mobile phone or the internet work – or my car, or television or, for that matter, my fridge – everything seems so comprehensively unknowable that amateurish scientific curiosity feels futile.(https://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/2016/jul/02/professor-brian-cox-interview-forces-of-nature)

Q: Can I use "I **can** imagine..." above instead of "I **could** imagine..."?

Comment: Definitely not with (1), because _as we walked_ indicates that it happened in the past.  (2) talks about imagining something that may happen in the future, so you could use **can**.  (3) is rather loosely expressed - Prof. Cox didn't imagine something 150 years ago, he is imagining what a person at that time might have thought.

Comment: As you say, (3) is loosely expressed. Would "I **can imagine**..." or simply "I **imagine**..." fit better in that context?

Comment: The meaning is clear, but to be strictly logical he could have said something like "If I had been alive 150 years ago, I can imagine myself gazing at a rainbow..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20can%20imagine%2C%20I%20could%20imagine&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20can%20imagine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20could%20imagine%3B%2Cc0) shows that both "I *could* imagine" and "I *can* imagine" have been used in literature, but "I **can** imagine" is consistently used more often. Evidently, neither are considered 'wrong', but in examples like yours, "I could..." doesn't really stand up to scrutiny, and it may be a case of something being said incorrectly so often it has become idiomatic.

"Could", used in this kind of context, refers only to a *possibility*, whereas "can" refers to something that is *allowable*.

In your first example, of someone saying "I *could* imagine myself sitting there coding all day", it sounds to me like they already *have* imagined it, otherwise they would not have been able to put it into words. Example 2 is similarly hypothetical. Personally, I would always say "I can..." in this kind of context.

Your third example is a little different, and somewhat confusing. It says "*A hundred and fifty years ago I could imagine....*". When we use "could" about the past, that is a very different usage and means things that we used to be able to do. It sounds like you are saying that you were able to do something 150 years ago, which doesn't make sense unless you are the oldest person alive. I think what you actually mean to say is that you *can* imagine a hypothetical situation that *could* have happened 150 years ago. You could perhaps say: "I can imagine myself, 150 years ago, gazing at a rainbow...".

Comment: So clearly written! I completely understand what you're trying to get across here. But I have a question. You say: *Example 2 is **similarly** hypothetical*... Do you mean the "could" in (1) is also *hypothetical*?

Comment: @Mr.X No - because the 'imagining' isn't the hypothetical part! You CAN imagine something hypothetical.

Comment: OK. To gain a better understanding of it, I think we could use "**was** able to" as a suitable paraphrase for the "could" in (1). But what about the "could" in (2)? Would you paraphrase it using "**was** able to" or would you use "**would/might** be able to"?